# Facebook ads click and page views

Tags: php, facebook, google-analytics, ads

anyone have problems with facebook ads click report and other statistic system report? 
I'm using facebook ads for my landing page with 3 reporting system: facebook / google analytics / my own

My own tracking system very simple, just log/count every single visit in to database so the flow looks like:

`facebook ads -> facebook redirect page (l.php) -> mypage.php ( I log the visit here) -> google analytics`

The difference between facebook and google analytics is reasonable (could be browser/js/cookie...). but mypage.php and facebook is different in statistic also (This is not understandable - *what happen in https://www.facebook.com/l.php?* )

There is only one reason, l.php is not redirect to mypage.php (so it can't log anything). The user's browser has to have javascript enabled for facebook to load and track clicks.

I never get more than 60% clicks come to mypage.php

Another thing, the percentage of it is different between countries.

Anyone has experience in this problem please help / explain.

Many thanks

Comment: how big of a difference are we talking?

Comment: currently I lost about 70% click, for each 100 clicks, it makes only 30 page views, there even be 11 page view / 100 click in Thailand.

Answer (score 1):

Jerry, I've just been to Facebook training and learned that Facebook clicks does not necessarily equal visits. Did some research and found many articles on this discrepancy, see this [official response from FB representative](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151721366611095).

Can you check (apart from visits) pageviews for the click-through pages?

**Anyway, I suggest you stick to one reporting tool and then observe any drops/lifts. Use UTM consistently.**

Comment: Hi Petr, Thanks for answer, but I think at least it should be less than 30% loss, I currently loss 70% of clicks. If click doesn't drive visitor to a url, where it will go to? 
I read you link from facebook, but that is google analytics, in my case, I count it immediately with php script (no need cookie/js/ajax...) still loss 70% of click. :(

Comment: Jerry, what type of posts are you looking at? Isn't CLICKS metric by any chance related to any click tracked (like zooming in the photo etc.?)